# JMeter/Selenium ChromeDriver thread shows it is interacting with element but nothing is happening on screen

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with using JMeter/Selenium Chrome WebDriver interacting with the element and making changes on the screen. When I look at the screen in non-headless mode nothing is happening on the screen on some of the threads. I am running 10 threads locally, waiting for a Username and Password input to display on the screen, send credentials with sendKeys and then clicking login.

The problem is, some of the threads and chrome instances are working but some others are not. I am not sure if it is a Chrome 99 issue as it seems to be happening to me recently even when I have the matching chromedriver.exe for 99. What I don't understand is why 7 or 8 will work while 2 or 3 say they are working but I cannot see it happening within the browser.

Here is a part of the Thread Group that I am running:

```
//Wait until the username field is visible.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='Input_Username']")));
WDS.log.info("element clickable");

//Enter user name
var txtUserName = WDS.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Input_Username']")); //saves username field into txtUserName
txtUserName.click();
txtUserName.clear();
txtUserName.sendKeys("username");
WDS.log.info("Enter UserName");

//Enter password
var txtPassword = WDS.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Input_Password']")); //saves password field into txtPassword
txtPassword.click();
txtPassword.clear();
txtPassword.sendKeys("password");
WDS.log.info("Enter password");

//Click Login in button
var btnLogin = WDS.browser.findElement(By.cssSelector('.btn')); //saves login field into btnLogin
btnLogin.click();
WDS.log.info("clicked login");
```

I can see every thread hitting each one of those log.info sections but I don't see the browser making any changes or key clicks. This leads me to believe it should be working, but the browser isn't being responsive for some reason? I am just confused on if I am missing something as to why some will work but some wont. It is moving past this piece of code but failing to make any interactions so it will fail on a wait later down the line when waiting for the page after login to be displayed.

I have even tried to implement a fluent wait with polling but it will say it found it, interact with it but nothing will change on the screen. It says it clicks the login button... which on the screen if nothing is entered into those fields I would at least be seeing validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using WebDriver Samplers for creating the load is a valid use case, as per [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

so you should be creating the main load using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and use a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 thread to test UI performance and rendering time while the system is under the load.

---

If you really want to use real browsers for conducting the load for some reason be aware that browsers are very resource intensive. Chrome doesn't state how much RAM does it need on its [system requirements page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en) but [Firefox 98](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/98.0/system-requirements/) needs 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance and my expectation is that Chrome needs the same amount (if not more)

So your system should have at least 11 CPU cores and 21 GB of RAM in order to operate 10 browsers and JMeter at the same time, if your machine hardware resources are less - consider either upgrading or obtaining another machine and switching to [distributed mode of JMeter tests execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)